# Persistent cookie being deleted as soon as Safari is closed and reopened (working fine in Chrome, Firefox)

Tags: javascript, ios, cookies, safari

I'm using the following JavaScript code to store a cookie with a ID in the browser of the website visitor for 60 days.

While it is working perfectly in Chrome, Firefox etc. in **Safari** the cookie disappears after closing and reopening the browser. (happens with iPhones, Macbooks etc., even in the standard cookie-configuration)

```
function setCookie() {
    const date = new Date;
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 60);
    var uid = Date.now().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
    document.cookie = "ck=" + uid + "; expires=" + date + "; path=/";
}
```

Does anyone have an idea, why this could be happening? Greetings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to set and read the cookie with php, now it is working. Maybe that is the better option anyways, since cookies set with document.cookie can only last maximum 7 days in Safari, before they get automatically deleted
([according to this overview](https://www.cookiestatus.com/))